# Creation of numpy array from two arrays, such that alternate indices contain elements from different arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking for a fast method to merge two numpy arrays in python in the following fashion. For example, if I have the following two arrays,

```
arr1 = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 11.0, 111.0])
arr2 = np.array([0.5, 1.5, 11.5, 111.5])
```

then I would want the merged array (say `arr3`) to contain elements of `arr1` and `arr2` in alternating indices. Like,

```
arr3 = np.array([0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 11.0, 11.5, 111.0, 111.5])
```

I realize that I can achieve this using two for loops, where I can store elements of `arr1` and `arr2` into alternate indices (of `arr3`). But, in my actual work, I will be dealing with huge arrays (`arr1` and `arr2`), and I want to make sure that I am using an efficient and fast approach to achieve this functionality (i.e. creation of `arr3`)

I will very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one way. Append or stack-based methods are inefficient, as memory is not pre-allocated. Manipulation of `numpy` arrays works best when memory allocation is determined ahead of time.

```
arr1 = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 11.0, 111.0])
arr2 = np.array([0.5, 1.5, 11.5, 111.5])

arr3 = np.zeros(arr1.shape[0] + arr2.shape[0], dtype=arr1.dtype)
arr3[::2] = arr1
arr3[1::2] = arr2

print(arr3)

[   0.     0.5    1.     1.5   11.    11.5  111.   111.5]
```

Comment: Roughly 3 times faster than the dstack + flatten solution with 1000-element arrays on my machine, cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way:

```
In []:
np.dstack((arr1, arr2)).flatten()

Out[]:
array([  0. ,   0.5,   1. ,   1.5,  11. ,  11.5, 111. , 111.5])
```